# Looking for disk-based alternative to Redis key-value store

Tags: database, redis, key-value

We have SQLite for RDBMS, but are there any disk-based, light-memory-usage key-value databases? In other words, a key-value store that can run on a *small amount of memory* with a *larger* amount of data. I would like to use it on lower-power machines with not a lot of free memory.

It seems that [BerkeleyDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB) and [LevelDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LevelDB) are both options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [MemcacheDB](http://memcachedb.org/).

Comment: MemcacheDB uses BurkeleyDB as a backend using the memcached protocol.   Performance is likely to be very similar to straight BDB.

Comment: They define it as _"persistent storage engine for fast and reliable key-value based object storage and retrieval"_ so I guess "fast" is relative. I assume it's fast for other disk-based solutions. You won't get as fast as with memory-based databases like Redis.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for a disk-based key-value store that is performant even when the data won't fit in memory.

Like @Ofer Zelig mentioned, fast is relative. But I think it's helpful to look at both the performance benchmarks and the operational guides for a given database. Many, including [Redis](http://redis.io/topics/faq), specify that you should provide enough memory so that all of the data (or all of the indexes) can fit in memory. That can be cost-prohibitive for some applications.

I suggest taking a look at FoundationDB. Its default [storage engine](https://foundationdb.com/key-value-store/documentation/configuration.html#storage-engines), 'ssd', is designed for large databases that don't fit in memory. The [performance benchmarks](https://foundationdb.com/key-value-store/performance) all use a large data set that doesn't fit in RAM, so you can see if that is fast enough for you.

As a bonus, FoundationDB is designed to run as a distributed cluster and supports multiple data models.

Full disclosure: I'm an engineer at FoundationDB.

Comment: Looks like it was too good to be true, so the fruit had to shut it down...